# Getting [Message clipped] in gmail

Tags: gmail

I've had GMail configured as a mailbox on my Windows Phone for almost a year now, and more recently, I've noticed that I cannot see the full message.

Instead of seeing the "Download message and internet pictures" link at the bottom of the message, I'm seeing "[Message clipped] view entire message". When I click on the "view entire message" hyperlink, I get an alert come up saying:

> Can't open link
>   The linkcan't be opeend from an email message
>   [ close ]

Is there a configuration setting that needs to be changed, either on GMail, or on the device, that will let me read email in my GMail account on my phone?

Comment: Are you connecting via IMAP, POP, or EAS?

Comment: @Nate it was added as a "google" account (i.e. with all the contact synchronisation as well) - it doesn't seem to identify the account type as any of those you mention

Comment: I believe that is EAS (at least for now). I have mine setup the same way. Have you tried deleting the account and re-adding it?

Comment: What version of windows phone is this?

Comment: @karancan 7.5 and 7.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, this issue only affected Windows Phone 7.5 and 7.8. Since upgrading to Windows Phone 8.0, I'm no longer seeing this issue.